# In URDF how do I get more than one geomtry element in a link?

Tags: rviz, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to build a simple robot model in urdf with just visualization and display it in rviz. I just have one tf frame for the body (it is a quad rotor) so how can I use the same frame for more than on geometry element?

Or is it possible to take a 3D model and just use that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55911/in-urdf-how-do-i-get-more-than-one-geomtry-element-in-a-link?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer is that you currently can't do exactly what you're saying.

The easiest way to get around it is to create a second link with an appropriate offset, connected with a fixed joint.

This does create an extra frame which will need to be published. This is most often handled with robot_state_publisher.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-02-21**:
I suppose I will get one extra frame per geomtry I want to have. I was afraid that would give possible delays but maybe it will work. I will test it. SO if I used tix joints I can use robot_state_publisher. I assume I could also just have no joints and just publish the frames from my program.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-02-21**:
robot_state_publisher is a little wonky, I think, in that it will only publish tfs when it gets joint state messages, so you may also need joint_state_publisher.

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-02-21**:
Joint state is not needed if you only have static links.
It is necessary with dynamic links.